# Stripe with apple watch extension

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, watchkit

I am using the pod Stripe for my ios app with watch extension. After add line
"pod 'Strip' "
in my pod file, run "pod install". My app cant compile. Xcode gives errors:
'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS(App Extension). I'd think
strip should fixed the sdk for apple watch support. What is solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

When using pods you need to make sure that your compiling from the .xcworkspace file instead of the .xcoderoj file.

Comment: When you run 'pods install' cocoapods will create a new file in your directory were your project is stored called projectname.xcworkspace, compiling from this file make sure that the stripe pod is linked up correctly.